# Does the ObjApp makes the app script slower?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My app script page loading time is a bit longer. I used the following functions. I am wondering, if the library object function makes the app script page loading time longer. If that is the case. how can I improve my code?

```
function getData() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('');
  var sheet=ss.getSheetByName('attendance');
  return sheet;
}


function dataresult() {
  var sheet = getData();
  var data = ObjApp.rangeToObjects(sheet.getDataRange().getValues());
  return data;
 }

Function sample()  {
for(var i=0 ; i< data.length;i++){
    var date= data[i].dateattend;
   }
}
```

Do you think this  function is better than the previous one in terms of loading time where I didn't use library?

```
function sample() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                       var date=  data[i][0]);
 }
}
```

Comment: It has to load the script, possibly from another served. So there will be *some* impact on loading times.

Comment: [https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries)

Comment: Do you think this function is better than the previous one in terms of loading time where I didn't use library?

function sample() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                       var date=  data[i][0]);
 }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using a library makes a script slower than non using the library, actually, Google doesn't allow the use of libraries on add-ons because of this.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I experimented two different scripts one using the library and another without using the library. It has a huge speed difference !!!